# Why does my toilet not leave enough water in the bowl after flushing?

Tags: toilet

A little while ago I started having trouble with my toilet when flushing. It's flushing too much water, leaving little left in the bowl. It also makes loud noises at the end of the flush.

There's still some water left in the tank, so when I flush it very carefully a second time I can get it to fill up just enough.

I'm in an apartment on the first floor (second if you're from the US), in case that matters.

What could be causing this?

Here's a picture of the tank:

[image]

Comment: Did the fill hose slip out of the overflow tube?

Comment: @Comintern I've added a picture to my question. From looking up a few pictures, I think there's a tube missing from the bottom going to the pipe at the center right?

Comment: @Stijn: Where did the hose go?

Comment: There should not be water "left" in the bowl after flushing; ideally, all the contents should vacate due to the siphoning action of the toilet's drain, though of course the action is not perfect.  Most of the new water you see in the bowl trickles in from the tank via the overflow while the tank is filling; that's most likely the issue (as others have noted).

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are missing your fill hose. There should be a hose connecting the outlet at the top of your fill valve assembly running into your overflow tube:

[image]